# Dynamically updating the output of a loop

Tags: output-formatting, output

Consider the following simple loop:

```
n=0;
Do[n++;Print[n],{10}]
```

Mathematica writes:

```
1

2

3

...
```

I want mathematica to write dynamically the value of the variable `n`. I mean I want Mathematica to write 1, cancel it and write 2, cancel it and write 3 and so on.

Is it possible?

Comment: Try `n=0;Dynamic[n]` and then (in a new line) `Do[n++;,{100000000}]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Monitor`

```
Monitor[Do[n++; Pause[.5], {10}], n]
```

`Monitor` can increase the time of a calculation. Use `Refresh` to control the update interval used for displaying:

```
 Monitor[Do[i, {i, 10^7}],
 Refresh[Pause[0.03] i, UpdateInterval -> 0.2, TrackedSymbols -> {}]]
```

Or as Henrik said in the comment `Dynamic`:

```
Do[n++; Pause[.5], {10}]
Dynamic[n]
```

But `Dynamic` is purely frontend function. `Monitor` is convinient for computation, for example for long running remote monitoring:

```
Monitor[Do[n++;, {3}], 
 SendMail["test@test.com", "n = " <> ToString[n]]]
```

BTW take a look at `Echo` too, might come handy, while not this case.